# PySide: multiple decorators for widget slots

Tags: python, qt, pyside

My main window class in Python with PySide has lots of member functions like:

```
@QtCore.Slot()
def on_myButton_clicked(self) :
    ...
```

I would like to add my own decorator, but the following does not work:'

```
def my_decorator(f) :
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) :
            f(*args, **kwargs)  
    return wrapper

...

@QtCore.Slot()
@my_decorator
def on_myButton_clicked(self) :
    ...
```

When I do this, `QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName` does not seem to connect the method with the button. Can this be easily fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`connectSlotsByName` works from the registered slots, and `Slot` works from the `__name__` of the function that it is given.

The name of `on_myButton_clicked` when it is defined is `'on_myButton_clicked'`. However, you then pass it through the decorator; the decorator function returns a function named `'wrapper'`. So `Slot` registers it with that name, *not* `'on_myButton_clicked'`.

To solve this, use [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
def my_decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This, among other things, sorts out `__name__` so that the slot will be registered under the correct name.

It's a good habit to *always* use `functools.wraps`; it will make debugging some situations easier.